# Decelerating car

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision

A car crashes into a immovable barrier at 60mph.

- (a)If the front-end of the car crumples a distance of 1.5 m in the collision, what is the deceleration experienced by the occupants? (Express your answer in g's)
- (b) What would be their deceleration (in gs) if it were instead going 90mph? Assume constant deceleration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. Use kinematic equation for constant acceleration: v^2=u^2+2as

Here v, the final velocity is 0 because the car comes to a stop, u is 60 mph, s is 1.5 m.
Therefore a= u^2/2s.

b. Just substitute u=90 mph and evaluate a in the same way.

Also to get the answers in g, just divide a by 9.8 m/s^2
Note: a will be negative